# Difference between Databricks Runtime ML & ML Flow

Tags: azure, databricks

I am a bit of a newbie to Azure Databricks though I have good experience with Databricks but only on Data Engg side. I am a bit confused about Databricks Runtime ML & ML Flow. What's the difference between them and when to use which one? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Databricks Runtime for Machine Learning (Databricks Runtime ML) provides a ready-to-go environment for machine learning and data science. It contains multiple popular libraries, including TensorFlow, PyTorch, Keras, and XGBoost along with the ability to do distributed deep learning.  IE A bunch of things are preinstalled on the databricks runtime and configured for you.
https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/clusters/mlruntime.html

MLFlow is an open source end to end machine learning life lifecycle platform.  MLFlow is a way to track experiment runs, deploy models, etc.
https://www.mlflow.org/

Comment: The first link is broken.